# Automating a curl script with external variables from text file

Tags: bash, http, curl

So I have a script located at

```
"http://somrething.com?source=<var1>&target=<var2>"
```

Which is taking two parameters (var1 & var2), both of which reside in a text/excel file.

```
var1 | var2

ab     cd
ef     gh
.      .
.      .
```

Say, there are n-entries in the above table and I want to execute my curl script n-times such that it picks up the entries, populates the query & executes. How should I go about doing so?

Currently, I am using a `python` script to execute this curl query as a bash command inside a loop after reading the text file and hopping on to the table entries one by one.

Something like this-

```
combined_vars = list(zip(var1, var2))

for var1, var2 in combined_vars:
    bashCommand = "curl 'http://somrething.com?source=" + var1 + "&target="+ var2+"'"
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
```

This script is in turn executed through a bash script since I need to automate this whole process with crontab.

This seems rather inefficient and I was wondering if there is an alternate way to do so.

Comment: @oguzismail done!

Comment: Is that example actually an excerpt from your text/excel file? And what is the point of that curl command? It just prints the source.

Comment: Edited again to include the near replica of what I've done so far. @oguzismail

Comment: Okay but you didn't answer my questions

Comment: @oguzismail 1, it is just an example. 2, there's a script in the background which is supposed to make some changes to the db after verifying the two params passed.

Comment: As a sidenote, `bashCommand.split()` is really prone to failure (it will split around whitespace without consideration for quotes), you'd probably better craft yourself the `[ "curl", url]` array

Comment: @Aaron Ah okay. I'll fix that. Any idea how to do the rest of it? Ideally, I'd like to do this straight up via terminal (and not through python).

Comment: More to the point, by "text/excel file" do you mean CSV? Can we expect specific cell and rows separators? If so calling curl once per row will be easily done by bash

Comment: @Aaron Yes, CSV is available with well defined separators.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your fields can't contain the field delimiter (which below is assumed to be `,`), using a while/read loop is enough :

```
while IFS=',' read var1 var2; do
    curl "http://somrething.com?source=$var1&target=$var2"
done < input.csv
```